# Reordering the search space

Tags: haskell, search

I try to find the first occurrence in the search space ordered by descending which satisfy a some predicate.

This strategy was chosen because calculating the predicate can be quite expensive, and the probability of finding a solution among the former is quite high.

Here is the solution, which first builds a list of all possible solutions, then arranges and produces a linear search.

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

search :: (Ord a, Num a) => ([a] -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> Maybe [a]
search p = find p . sortOn (Down . sum) . sequence
```

## Example

```
main = print $ search ((<25) . sum) [[10,2], [10,8,6], [8]]
```

## Output

```
Just [10,6,8]
```

## Question

Is there a way to generate elements of this space in descending order without sorting?

Comment: In your solution you don't save any time by precomputing the sum and sorting the lists based on that, because you do it twice anyway (in `sortOn (Down . sum)` and in your predicate `search ((<25) . sum))`. I'm guessing that `sum` is your expensive part of the computation. What do you mean by descending order? The lists sum sorted by descending order?

Comment: `foldr (\xs yss -> (:) <$> xs <*> yss) [[]]` is more idiomatically spelled `sequence`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, thank you!

Comment: @Cirquit >> The lists sum sorted by descending order? - Yes! Calculating the sum isn't a problem for my domain, the real predicate does not compute it, it's just an example.

Comment: @Cirquit - The predicate calculation is much longer than the sum.

Comment: I'm still a little confused by the problem domain. How do you want to have a list in descending order, without sorting it? You want `search` to traverse the list in descending order based on another predicate (in your case `Down . sum`), while filtering for the initial predicate `(<25 . sum)`. If that's the case, I don't think that there's a possibility to do that. If performance is an issue, you might consider to enforce strictness with the pragma `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}`, and try this `let !sorted = (sortOn (Down . sum) . sequence) [[10,2], [10,8,6], [8]] in find ((<25) . sum) sorted`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The exact case described

In this exact case, there is a clear best element in the space, and if any element matches the predicate then the best one does:

```
-- I have, over the years, found many uses for ensure
ensure p x = x <$ guard p x
search p = ensure p . map minimum
```

## `(<25) . sum` is a placeholder, but `Down . sum` is exact

If your predicate is just an example, but your heuristic is really summing, you can use a priority queue to search through the space. For simplicity, I'll use `[(b,a)]` as my priority queue with priorities `b` and values `a`, maintaining the invariant that the list is sorted by `b`. Of course you should use a better implementation if you want efficiency.

And now we basically just reimplement `sequence` to produce its elements in priority order and maintain the sum of the lists it produces as their priority. Introducing the priority queue invariant is a small one-time cost up front.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

increasingSums :: (Ord a, Num a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
increasingSums = map snd . go . map sort where
    go [] = [(0,[])]
    go (xs:xss) = let recurse = go xss in mergeOn fst
        [ [ (total+h, h:ts)
          | (total, ts) <- recurse
          ]
        | h <- xs
        ]
```

The only thing missing is `mergeOn`, which flattens a collection of priority queues into a single one:

```
mergeOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [a]
mergeOn f = go . sortOn (f . head) . filter (not . null) where
    go [] = []
    go ([x]:xss) = x : go xss
    go ((x:xs):xss) = x : go (insertBy (comparing (f . head)) xs xss)
```

Testing in `ghci`, we can see that this expression finishes in a non-stupid amount of time:

```
> take 10 . increasingSums . replicate 4 $ [1..1000]
[[1,1,1,1],[2,1,1,1],[1,2,1,1],[1,1,2,1],[1,1,1,2],[2,1,1,2],[1,2,1,2],[1,1,2,2],[1,1,1,3],[2,1,2,1]]
```

Whereas this expression does not:

```
> take 10 . sortOn sum . sequence . replicate 4 $ [1..1000]
^C^C^C^COMG how do I quit
```

Meanwhile it is also competitive for producing the complete list of sums in sorted order (at least before compilation, I didn't test whether the optimized versions are also about equal):

```
> :set +s
> sum . map sum . increasingSums . replicate 4 $ [1..30]
50220000
(1.99 secs, 1,066,135,432 bytes)
> sum . map sum . sortOn sum . sequence . replicate 4 $ [1..30]
50220000
(2.60 secs, 2,226,497,344 bytes)
```

## `Down . sum` is a placeholder

Finally, if your heuristic is just an example, and you want a fully general solution that will work for all heuristics, you're out of luck. Doing a structured walk through your search space requires knowing something special about that structure to exploit. (For example, above we know that if `x<y` then `total+x<total+y`, and we exploit this to cheaply maintain our priority queue.)

Comment: By the way, this was a fun problem! I ended up with at least five or six failed attempts before hitting on this one.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try to understand your solution. It's look like should to work. And, If I want to generalize. Is it enough that the constituent elements are from the set on which the Group or Ring or Field is formed? So, what kind an algebraic structure should be?

Comment: @freestyle I think the only thing this algorithm assumes about the structure is what I said in the last paragraph: that `x<y` implies `total+x<total+y` (and that `0` exists, of course).

Comment: if I understand correctly, `increasingSums = map snd . go . map sort` can be simplify to `increasingSums = map snd . go`?

Comment: @freestyle Oops, yes, I'm doing some redundant sorting. You can either remove the `map sort` from `increasingSums` or remove the `sortOn (f . head)` from `mergeOn`.